# What does "synthetic beings" mean?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, eternals-2021, eternals

In *Eternals* (2021), Celestial Arishem says to Sersi:

> Celestial Arishem: I built and programmed you, Eternals, to be **synthetic beings**
> and incapable of evolution, to correct my mistake.

What does "synthetic beings" mean?

Comment: My guess is it means they were "man-made" instead of existing naturally, although I never watched it so it's just a wild guess.

Comment: [https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/synthetic#Adjective (definition 4)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/synthetic#Adjective), [https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/being#Noun (definition 1)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/being#Noun)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arishem here is most probabably referring to the Eternals being Synthetic beings that is as defined by Google as **made by a chemical process; not natural**.

He is just reminding them that they were not natural i.e they were not naturally born through biological processes and that they were made by the Celestials artificially.

Answer (score 0):

Eternals takes place within the Marvel Cinematic Universe, so it's most likely that Arishem was using the definition established earlier on in the MCU during Age of Ultron, and later codified in Wandavision, in regards to the character Vision.

Vision is considered to be a Synthetic being (as opposed to an artificial Artificial being like Ultron), because he was manufactured for a specific purpose using inorganic materials with the goal of replicating an existing form (Vision was created to appear human), rather than being created for a specific task (as in the body that Ultron took over).

In essence, they are synthetic because they were designed from the ground up to appear to be human, rather than having been born, evolved, or having taken over a form.